# Simple way to get CPU load from Windows Server via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

Trying to put together a script for getting the current CPU load from a set of servers using PowerShell. Is there a simple way to do this. I am using Get-WmiObject win32_processor  | select LoadPercentage.

Basically I am trying to get CPU load and display red if above 75% usage and green if below 75% usage. Preferably with the load percentage displayed.

So far I have this incomplete and possibly totally wrong:

```
$Servers = Get-QADComputer -sizelimit 0 | where {$_.Name -like "*myserver*"} | select Name
foreach($Server in $Servers){
    $I = $Server.Name
    $result = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $Server.Name | select LoadPercentage | ft 
    if($result -eq $null){
    Write-Host $Server.LoadPercentage "Less than 75% CPU Load" -ForegroundColor "Green"
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the CPU and RAM usage using Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298941/how-do-i-find-the-cpu-and-ram-usage-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `$Servers` collection to be populated with host names, you are not that far off. I don't have the Quest tools, so am unable to check the collection.

```
# Best practice: avoid mistyped variable names
set-psdebug -strict
$Servers = Get-QADComputer -sizelimit 0 | where {$_.Name -like "*myserver*"} | select Name
# Best practice: avoid magic numbers; readonly variable for 
new-variable -name CPULIMIT -value 75 -option readonly

foreach($Server in $Servers){
    $result = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $Server.Name
    # TODO: add error handler here in case $server is unavailable
    # Compare the wmi query result to the limit constant
    if($result.LoadPercentage -le $CPULIMIT){
        # Write a formatted string that contains the server name and current load
        Write-Host $("Less than 75% CPU Load on {0} ({1}%)" -f $server, $result.LoadPercentage) -ForegroundColor "Green"
    } else {
        # A warning message would be usefull too
        Write-Host $("Over than 75% CPU Load on {0} ({1}%)" -f $server, $result.LoadPercentage) -ForegroundColor "Red"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats certainly returns a result which is great, it doesnt return the load % though.

For example I get the result: Less than 75% CPU Load on MYSERVER2 (%)

Any ideas?

Thank you so much thats a great help.

Comment: @user2707263, Run  Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName myserver2 and check if there is sensible a value on the LoadPercentage attribute.

Comment: Yes, it gives an accurate load value at the time for example:

Level                       : 6
LoadPercentage              : 2
Manufacturer                : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed               : 2933
Name                        : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5670  @ 2.93GHz