# Get system information from command line interface

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface, system-information

I'm trying to create a script, that when run, will output a text file of that computer's specs.

Is there a program that offers command line interface to generating a text file containing simplified computer specifications on a Windows OS?

Just the basic consumer info. ie: RAM, CPU, HDD, etc.. I don't need or want every last detail about the computer.

I understand that MSinfo32, DxDiag, Speccy, offer export features however Speccy doesn't offer automation through CLI, and the other two simply export a glob of all system info. Much of which is personal and unnecessary for what I need.

The only two workarounds I can think of is to either use a Windows equivalent of a grep/cat/awk command to sift out only the necessary info. Which could prove to be quite tedious seeing as how each system would, obviously, have different specs. Alternatively, use a program (if one exists) to specify which specs to gather and which ones to leave out.

Comment: You may use `Powershell`, but there is a learning curve. See on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) first.

Comment: Many langauges, [even cmd](http://betanews.com/2011/01/14/wmic-the-best-command-line-tool-you-ve-never-used/), support [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That would be the route I would take for this. PowerShell could do this nicer but you have to know how to use it for it to be most effective. You could start searching here for WMI PowerShell answers. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298941/how-do-i-find-the-cpu-and-ram-usage-using-powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In powershell:

```
$System = Get-CimInstance CIM_ComputerSystem
$BIOS = Get-CimInstance CIM_BIOSElement
$OS = Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem
$CPU = Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor
$HDD = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = 'C:'"
$EXTXT = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\welp.txt"
Clear-Host

"Manufacturer: " + $System.Manufacturer >> $EXTXT
"Model: " + $System.Model >> $EXTXT
"CPU: " + $CPU.Name >> $EXTXT
"RAM: " + "{0:N2}" -f ($System.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB) + "GB" >> $EXTXT
"HDD Capacity: "  + "{0:N2}" -f ($HDD.Size/1GB) + "GB" >> $EXTXT
"Operating System: " + $OS.caption >> $EXTXT
```

The replies to my question got me better search results. Most of the source code is from here: http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show_download/1831
I was able to piece together the appending and stuff afterwards. Save as .ps1 format and it's good to go.

Or if you prefer here's the same, relative, script written in Python. Using native Windows and PowerShell commands.

```
import os
import wmi
import math

c = wmi.WMI()    
SYSINFO = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]
OSINFO = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0]
CPUINFO = c.Win32_Processor()[0]
HDDINFO = c.Win32_LogicalDisk()[0]
RAMINFO = c.Win32_PhysicalMemory()[0]

MANUFACTURER = SYSINFO.Manufacturer
MODEL = SYSINFO.Model
RAMTOTAL = int(SYSINFO.TotalPhysicalMemory)
HDDTOTAL = int(HDDINFO.size)
RAMSIZE = round(RAMTOTAL)
HDDSIZE = round(HDDTOTAL)

os.system('cls')
print "Model: " + MANUFACTURER + " " + MODEL
print "\r"
print "HDD: " + str(HDDTOTAL) + "GB"
print "RAM: " + str(RAMTOTAL) + "GB"
print "CPU: " + CPUINFO.name
print "OS: " + OSINFO.caption
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from PowerShell, WMIC is a built-in command line tool which is designed for reporting WMI data, including all kinds of system information, and outputting it in various formats.  It doesn't have a canned system hardware report, but you can use it to get exactly the settings you want.

For example, to list the drives on the computer, I can issue the following:

```
C:\>wmic diskdrive get  Manufacturer,Partitions,Size /value
Manufacturer=(Standard disk drives)
Partitions=2
Size=320070320640
```

...

Or if you want a boatload of info about a particular item, you can use this:

```
wmic cpu list /format:list

AddressWidth=64
Architecture=9
Availability=3
Caption=Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5
ConfigManagerErrorCode=
ConfigManagerUserConfig=
CpuStatus=1
CreationClassName=Win32_Processor
CurrentClockSpeed=2794
CurrentVoltage=
DataWidth=64
Description=Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5
DeviceID=CPU0
```

...

```
LoadPercentage=24
Manufacturer=GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed=2794
Name=Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           W3530  @ 2.80GHz
```

This site shows some excellent examples for [WMIC or PowerShell](http://acidx.net/wordpress/2012/09/retrieving-system-information-via-command-line-on-windows/)

Microsoft has the [full documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779482%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) online, but it doesn't really give you a feel for how to use it.