# how to calculate the total system load in a script based upon wmic outputs?

Tags: cmd, cpu-usage, windows-7-x64, wmic, system-information

when i use the below mentioned command line on Windows 7 or similar in a cmd.exe shell on a laptop i get something like this:

```
    C:\>wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value | find "LoadPercentage"
    LoadPercentage=15
```

doing the very same on a server class machine gives me something like this:

```
    C:\>wmic cpu get LoadPercentage /value | find "LoadPercentage"
    LoadPercentage=48
    LoadPercentage=50
```

-- a bit of a backgrounder for why the outputs might be different...

doing a systeminfo on the laptop (German language Windows) looks like this:

```
    C:\>systeminfo
    [...]
    Prozessor(en): 1 Prozessor(en) installiert.
                   [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 30 Stepping 5 GenuineIntel ~1734 MHz
```

doing the same on the server looks like this:

```
    C:\>systeminfo
    [...]
    Processor(s): 2 Processor(s) Installed.
                  [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2600 Mhz
                  [02]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4 GenuineIntel ~2600 Mhz
```

-- backgrounder end.

my question is now:

how can i get the total sum of system load on the shell all the time? (instead of this per-processor listing as provided in the server case)

maybe some cmd.exe magic is possible or maybe something else than 'wmic' will serve me better in that case.
i probably want to stick with standard programs and tools instead of adding third party software. thus the solution hopefully would run everywhere.

Comment: I was just about to post a PS one liner as an answer but I found there is already one posted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6298963/1123692

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the CPU and RAM usage using Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298941/how-do-i-find-the-cpu-and-ram-usage-using-powershell)

Comment: i followed the first link. its indeed about PS and not about cmd.exe. this raises me the question on how to execute PS only commands from cmd.exe (e.g. writing the results to a file or to an environment variable.

checking this proposed command line:
        Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage  |fl
gives me two result lines, not a single one - Problem still there.

this proposal:
        Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
gives me a single number of "2". not what i am expecting for the current load.

Comment: using this:
        Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time'
gives me a multi line result with the desired data looking separated. a ' | find "." ' would do the job for cmd.exe - but not for PS.
this one does not work for non-english windows versions.

Comment: for interaction between cmd.exe and PS i found this topic:

http://serverfault.com/questions/349585/how-do-i-set-an-environmental-variable-from-a-powershell-command

coming close to a working solution now...