# Diagnosing high Azure cloud service CPU usage which doesn't show in the profiling report

Tags: azure, monitoring, cpu-usage, azure-cloud-services

I have a simple Azure cloud service with one web role, no worker roles, and two instances. It's configured to use A0 instances. When I deploy it, the portal monitoring system shows CPU usage around 98%, and it doesn't drop to sensible levels even overnight.

However, if I download a profiling report it shows essentially 0% CPU usage. This isn't surprising, because I'm not actually calling the service yet. Scaling back to one instance while the service is running sometimes causes the CPU usage to drop to something sensible (below 10%), but not always.

I tried to remote desktop to one of the instances, but when they're pegging the virtual CPU the response time is too high for remote desktop: packet sniffing shows that I'm not even getting a TCP ACK back before RD displays an "Unable to connect" error. I do have the cloud service configured to receive RD, because when the CPU isn't above 90% I can connect.

I see that for Azure Websites there's a tool (Kudu Process Monitor) which provides info on CPU usage, but it doesn't seem to be available for cloud services.

Are there any other tools available to see what's using the CPU?

Comment: I've seen this on Worker Roles when I've barfed the OnStart() or Run() methods which throw an exception and cause the role to continuously recycle. If you look on the instance tab, does the Role show as 'running' or 'busy....Calling OnStart()' etc?

Comment: @NickHeppleston, it shows as running, and my logs show the initialisation code being executed once.

Comment: Bummer. Do you get the same CPU usage in the emulator when running locally?

Comment: No, although I don't think the emulator is really emulating much. It certainly doesn't seem to take long enough to start up to be deploying a full VM.

Comment: It doesn't host the full VM, its just running your code in the WaWorkerHost.exe process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: remote PowerShell**

Remote PowerShell is less fussy about latency than Remote Desktop, so once you configure it to be available then it's possible to connect to an instance which is running at 98% CPU and use `Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time'` with whatever subsequent [formatting pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819444/573420) you want. The trick is to enable it.

I followed the instructions in an MS blog post on [Remote Powershell to Azure PaaS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/golive/archive/2014/11/28/use-remote-powershell-to-manage-your-azure-paas-compute-instances.aspx), but they didn't work perfectly for me. To be specific, the user creation seems to have failed silently, because the log showed the user as created but the control panel's list of users didn't. So modified instructions are:

1. In the `.csdef` file, inside the `<WebRole>` config add

   ```
   <Startup>
     <Task commandLine="EnableWinRM.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
   </Startup>
   ```

   and inside `<WebRole><Endpoints>` add

   ```
   <InstanceInputEndpoint name="WinRM" localPort="5986" protocol="tcp">
     <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
       <FixedPortRange min="30000" max="30100" />
     </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
   </InstanceInputEndpoint>
   ```
2. In the web role's project, add a file `EnableWinRM.cmd` with *Copy Always*:

   ```
   PowerShell -command Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
   PowerShell .\EnableWinRM.ps1
   exit /B 0
   ```

   and a file `EnableWinRM.ps1` with *Copy Always* (replacing the thumbprint and hostname):

   ```
   $thumbprint = '<< Thumbprint for a suitable certificate >>'
   $certId = '<< Hostname >>'
   winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS `@`{Hostname=`"($certId)`"`;  CertificateThumbprint=`"($thumbprint)`"`}
   Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2000
   ```
3. Enable Remote Desktop via `manage.windowsazure.com`'s *Configure* tab, selecting *Remote* in the bottom task bar. The point of doing this is to create a privileged user with known username and password, because that's the user I used to connect in the next step.
4. Connect with PowerShell using the Remote Desktop user:

   ```
   $cred = Get-Credential
   Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <<Hostname>> -Port 30000 -UseSSL -Credential $cred
   ```

---

PS For anyone who's curious, the excessive CPU usage is attributed to `vsperf`.