# How to record the load on CPU for a particular time period?

Tags: powershell, monitoring, cpu-usage, cpu-load

I am trying to record the load on the CPU for certain time period using PowerShell. Is there any way to record the CPU utilization in the task manager?
I have tried this: [Tracking CPU and Memory usage per process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/tracking-cpu-and-memory-usage-per-process). But it didn't work.

Comment: What about: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298941/how-do-i-find-the-cpu-and-ram-usage-using-powershell)

Comment: Thank you @Jelphy. I have tried it. It gives the current load on the CPU but i want to define the time period and get the average CPU load for that time period.

Comment: Why not use Perfmon?

Comment: Thanks @vonPryz. But none of the counters in performance monitor gives the CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Get-Counter` cmdlet with the `SampleInterval` parameter:

```
$interval = 20 #seconds
$counterSample = Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time' -SampleInterval $interval
$avgLoad = $counterSample.CounterSamples.CookedValue
```

Comment: Thanks @Mathias R. Jessen. I have tried it but I am not sure if it gives the CPU usage. The value i got here and the value in the resource monitor CPU usage is different.

Comment: How do you get an average over 20 seconds from Resource Monitor?