# Retrieving CPU details in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am planning to extract the CPU details to my powershell requirement. Below is the highlighted parameter that I am trying to extract.

[image]

I have tried using *Get-WmiObject Win32_Process* or *Get-Process* but no luck with it. Can you guide with the cmdlet which can be helpful for this

Updated Question

```
Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | 
    Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| 
      Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | 
        Select-Object| ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100).toString('P')}} -AutoSize
```

I am using this code as suggested in the below comments. and below is the output which I am receiving.

[image]

However if you compare the value for PS output and the task manager screenshot, its quite different, since in task manager most of them are 0

Updated Part 2

I have extracted this code from another post.

```
$NumberOfLogicalProcessors=(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_processor | Measure-Object -Sum NumberOfLogicalProcessors).Sum
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').Countersamples  | Sort cookedvalue -Desc | ft -a instancename, @{Name='CPU %';Expr={[Math]::Round($_.CookedValue / $NumberOfLogicalProcessors)}}
```

This may be working, but I would like to get your opinions on these since the value for this is dynamic and pretty difficult to verify

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943928/listing-processes-by-cpu-usage-percentage-in-powershell)?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: @Paolo I am looking to extract "CPU" from the above through powershell for further processing

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819444/3390419

Comment: @Paolo They return values in % which is above 100 and the above image which I have posted has mostly zero's in them

Comment: @BillJetzer Its not returning the value as expected since most of values should be zero as show in the above image

Comment: PLEASE, show your code that is not working as wanted. it is _quite_ difficult to discuss code that no one here has seen ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Apologies for that, I have updated the question, please check now.

Comment: task manager _does not_ work the same way as the system counters. not only do they report at different times ... the two methods appear to calculate the averages differently. as long as the numbers are in the same general order of magnitude, you are likely getting "correct"  numbers. ///// you can use the `-SampleInterval` & `-MaxSamples` to get data over a span of time.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the inputs. I have updated my question again with a query that I was able to find from another post. Please check and let me know if that script should just work fine?

Comment: @SQLDoctor - that looks good & runs well [after fixing the stuff that the formatting ate]. i would likely switch to using `Select-Object` instead of `ft` since the `Format-*` cmdlets are only for final display ... and i might want to use the info in another step.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for the correction

Comment: @SQLDoctor - you are welcome ... [*grin*]

Comment: Lee_Dailey MVP haha

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$Utilization = @()
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Sort-Object -Property PercentProcessorTime -descending | ? { $_.name -inotmatch '_total|idle' } | % {$Utilization += [PSCustomObject]@{'Process Name' = $_.Name; 'pid' = $_.IDProcess; 'Usage' = $_.PercentProcessorTime}}
```