# How to get CPU and RAM usage without psutil

Tags: python, windows, cpu, ram

For security reasons, I am not allowed to use any packages downloaded from pypi, including PSUTIL.
Is there a way to be able to retrieve the CPU Usage and RAM Usage without it?

I believe there is already an existing question for this with a solution where I can read `/proc/stat`, but that is not an option for me, because I am using Windows server, not linux.

I was thinking maybe I can execute a "get CPU/RAM Usage" shell command and printing the output in Python using subprocess module, but I'm getting an error. Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select LoadPercentage', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

result.stdout
```

I'm getting a "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" error.

More detailed error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\acer\Documents\Test.py", line 2, in <module>
    result = subprocess.run(['Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select LoadPercentage', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: "I was thinking maybe I can execute a "get CPU/RAM Usage" shell command and printing the output in Python, but I'm not sure how I would go about that." did you look up how to execute shell commands in Python?

Comment: since psutil is open source, you can have a look at the source code to find some leads.

Comment: "Not sure how I would go about that": Are you unsure about how to execute a shell command, or what shell command will give you CPU and RAM usage in Windows?

Comment: [Maybe this would help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6320606/7867968)

Comment: @stuckoverflow Unfortunately looking at psutil's source won't probably help OP much, since the [main logic is in C](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/df3fba560125a1694140418458d85076ebc546fd/psutil/arch/windows/cpu.c) and given OP's boss, I doubt they can download a C compiler - who knows what sneaky security breaches those are!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I know the shell command to get CPU and RAM Usage in Windows; However, I don't know how to get that output and use it in Python. I've tried using the subprocess module, but failed to.

Comment: Cool, please show _what you tried_ as a [mre], and describe how it failed to meet your requirements. [ask] | [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've editted my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.run` runs your command in the windows command prompt. To run it in powershell, you need to first invoke powershell in the command prompt. You can do this simply by prepending `"powershell"` to your list of arguments

```
result = subprocess.run(['powershell', 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select LoadPercentage'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print(result.stdout)
```

prints

```
b'\r\nLoadPercentage\r\n--------------\r\n             5\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

Since this output is of type `bytes`, you'll have to decode it and parse the number out of it. I `split` the result and selected the last element, but you can use any other method you prefer:

```
result_s = result.stdout.decode("ascii")
cpu_load = int(result_s.split()[-1])        # gives cpu_load = 5
```

---

Note that I removed your `'-l'` argument because that causes an error on my computer. I am not familiar with the `Select` command (or any powershell, really) to tell you how to fix it, but it seems irrelevant to the question anyway.

```
Select-Object : Missing an argument for parameter 'Last'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Int32' and try again.
At line:1 char:62
+ Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor | Select LoadPercentage -l
+                                                              ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

Comment: You can also add `encoding='utf-8'` to the `subprocess.run` invocation to avoid having to decode things yourself.